# Pass the data between the view controllers via prepare without connecting Show segue in the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I did a show segue connection between the view controllers using code without using a storyboard. So I can not specify the segue.identifier, so I can not pass the data.

**Connections between view controllers without storyboards**

```
private func tableOfContentsBtnConfig() {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "contents"), for: .normal)
    button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickOnButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationItem.titleView = button
}

@objc func clickOnButton() {
    let chapterVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChapterViewController") as! ChapterViewController

    self.present(chapterVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Data can not be passed**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    guard let destination = segue.destination as? ChapterViewController else { return }

    destination.bookNo = self.bookNo
}
```

I found through log debugging that this function does not run at all. I think it's probably because segue.identifier is not specified, how can I specify an identifier without using the storyboard? Or are there other solutions?

Comment: Please choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare for segue method will not be called in this scenario
You can use the following code:

```
@objc func clickOnButton() {
    let chapterVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChapterViewController") as! ChapterViewController
    chapterVC.bookNo = self.bookNo
    self.present(chapterVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the property in your selector method:

```
@objc func clickOnButton() {
    let chapterVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChapterViewController") as! ChapterViewController
    chapterVC.bookNo = self.bookNo
    self.present(chapterVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote below code

```
 @objc func clickOnButton() {
        let chapterVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChapterViewController") as! ChapterViewController

        self.present(chapterVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

It automatically present the `ChapterViewController` w/o any segue and if you wanted to push then use `self.navigationController.push(...)`  instead of `self.present(...)`

---

**Note** : Segues are components of storyboard. If you don't have a storyboard, you can't perform segues.

**Reference** : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboardsegue